# Get timing for when the kubernetes container passed liveness and readiness

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability

I have a pod with the following spec for one of the container:

```
      livenessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /liveness
          port: http
          scheme: HTTP
        initialDelaySeconds: 10
        timeoutSeconds: 1
        periodSeconds: 10
        successThreshold: 1
        failureThreshold: 1
      readinessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /readiness
          port: http
          scheme: HTTP
        initialDelaySeconds: 10
        timeoutSeconds: 1
        periodSeconds: 300
        successThreshold: 1
        failureThreshold: 3
```

I have doubt on how long it took for the pod to be considered ready and added to the service. My fear is the initialDelaySeconds is too short and force the pod to wait 300s for another readiness to be triggered and the pod to be considered healthy.

Is there a way I could see the precise timing of each events from pod schedule to container readiness?

If I describe on the pod, I can see the Events but they aren't detailed enough. Also is there a way to have them using full date format. The pod has a value "Start Time" but also the containers, what do they represent, time for container to be running (but still under /liveness and /readiness check)? Time for container to be Ready?